# Is there some research about infinitely many-armed bandit with non-stationary assumption?

Tags: ds.algorithms, reference-request, machine-learning

Is there some research about **infinitely many-armed bandit** with **non-stationary** assumption? I have found [the paper](https://faculty.wharton.upenn.edu/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/Bandit-problems-with-infinitely-many-arms.pdf) about infinitely many-armed bandit under stationary (or stochastic) assumption. And I also found the solution for non-stationary multi-armed bandit problem, like [discounted UCB](https://arxiv.org/abs/0805.3415). Are there some attempts to this mixed problems?